# How do I get an MEA attestation on my educational certificates?

Tags: india, education-visa

I am looking for Ministry of External Affairs attestation for my educational certificates in India. Can Anyone guide me through the procedure of MEA Attestation?

Comment: Have you looked at https://mea.gov.in/apostille.htm?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it but didn't get the detailed information which I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEA is a central government administration. It is a certification department that verifies documents issued from India. MEA is one of the most significant processes for all types of documents.

[image]

**What is MEA Attestation?**

MEA Attestation is an external authentication department that is used to receiving the sticker from central government authorities on your certificates. This central government department deals with external affairs that are related to outside nations. When anyone looking for any authentication procedure in India at that time it is necessary to validate your documents and certificates from ministry. This document verification process is necessary to prove the credibility and genuinity of your documents.

**MEA Attestation Procedure**

The central government certification process includes lots of levels for certificate verification before verifying the certificates. The procedure of central document authentication totally depends upon the type of certificates i.e. personal, educational and commercial. The levels involved in the procedure are:-

1)**Regional level:**

It is the first stage of the certificate verification process. This level of legalization can be done by the notary or the University from where the certificates were issued, as per the specification or from the Chamber of commerce in the case of commercial documents.

2)**State Attestation:**

The legalization of certificates from the state is performed by three different organizations as per the need of the document type. These departments are the State Home Department Attestation, Human Resource Department, and the Sub-Divisional Magistrate. SDM is independent of the state government, however, the attestation performed by this authority is considered on the state level.

3)**MEA attestation:**

Ministry of External Affairs Attestation is the last stage of legalization from the home government after which an MEA sticker is applied to the certificate. MEA is the central organization that concerns with the foreign affairs of the nation.
MEA Attestation for Educational Certificates

Depending on the origin or type of the certificate, the process for the attestation of educational certificates will vary. The following are given the different methods that are specific to the place of issuance of the certificate and its kind.

1. **For Maharashtra issued Documents:**-

[image]

2. **For out of Maharashtra issued Documents:-**

[image]

3. **As per the Embassy requirement where HRD compulsory:-**

[image]

MEA Attestation procedure in India can be both, complex and time-taking. However, it can be made reachable and facile with the indulgence of attestation provider vendors who're capable of supplying MEA attestation service and help for the duration of the entire method. The professional certificate attestation services are a feasible alternative to get the certificate attestation.